# Can't decode handshake request from client

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, encoding, compression

I'm trying to connect a python3 socket with a JavaScript WebSocket. I'm testing the server code on localhost:8080, and connecting with Chrome(94.0).

The WebSocket client and the socket server **do** establish a connection. However, the connection would be shut down if the server did not follow the protocol and respond to the  handshake. According to the protocol, the client WebSocket sends a utf-8 encoded GET request to the socket server, and the server must parse that request in order to complete the handshake.

What I get from the client is this:

```
\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xfc\x03\x03\x97t\xb1\xf7\xac\x99\x91\xd4\xf5\n\xdf\xc3X\x8af<\xbe\x99(0\x88\x9a!\xc6\xc9\x17]\xfe\xd9sP\xcc \xa8\xcf\x90{\x8a\xfcm\xbcj-5\xdf\xf90\x81\xc8Y\xc1\x85q"\xfe!C\xbb\t\xbd}\xe0\x8d\xf1\xe5\x00 \x1a\x1a\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03\xc0+\xc0/\xc0,\xc00\xcc\xa9\xcc\xa8\xc0\x13\xc0\x14\x00\x9c\x00\x9d\x00/\x005\x01\x00\x01\x93\x1a\x1a\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\xff\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\n\x00\n\x00\x08\xfa\xfa\x00\x1d\x00\x17\x00\x18\x00\x0b\x00\x02\x01\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x12\x00\x10\x04\x03\x08\x04\x04\x01\x05\x03\x08\x05\x05\x01\x08\x06\x06\x01\x00\x12\x00\x00\x003\x00+\x00)\xfa\xfa\x00\x01\x00\x00\x1d\x00 \xfa)\xd5\x85<\x81.\x7f\xc0\x87wA!\xf1\xc9\xf80\xeb\x01\xdc\xed3m\xd1\x98\xd6\xd8\xd7\x7f#\rM\x00-\x00\x02\x01\x01\x00+\x00\x0b\n\x8a\x8a\x03\x04\x03\x03\x03\x02\x03\x01\x00\x1b\x00\x03\x02\x00\x02JJ\x00\x01\x00\x00\x15\x00\xf7\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

The client consistently sends these bytes, although it this does not look like a legitimate GET request. This can't be decoded by utf-8 or by other encodings including utf-16-le, utf-16-be, unicode-escape, etc.

client source:

```
var client = new WebSocket('wss://127.0.0.1:8080')

client.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("open");
}

client.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data)
}
```

server handshake handler:

```
def handshake(client, address):
    req = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    key = (re.search('Sec-WebSocket-Key:\s+(.*?)[\n\r]+', req).groups()[0].strip())
    response_key = b64encode(sha1(key + sockey).digest())
    response = '\r\n'.join(websock_ans).format(key=response_key)
    client.send(response.encode('utf-8'))
```

As the client request isn't utf-8 bytes, this gives a decoding error in line 2.

following the websocket protocol (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455), sockey and websock_ans are defined as follows:

```
sockey = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
websock_ans = {
    'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols',
    'Upgrade: websocket',
    'Connection: Upgrade',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {key}\r\n\r\n',
}
```

Does WebSocket compress/encrypt its GET requests? As far as I checked, the documents do not state any compression/encryption algorithms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since it isn't UTF-8, why don't you remove `.decode('utf-8')` and see what the bytes are?

Comment: you are right - this is the original code. The bytes I received from the client are mentioned in the first snippet starting with \x16\x03\x01\...

Answer (score 0):

Use *gzip* to convert the bytes into objects.

Comment: I've tried to find references for it, but couldn't find ones for WebSockets. Does websocket compress, and if so, what arguments does it use?